# Attach onAnimationComplete for Chart.js after creation

Tags: chart.js, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm creating a [Blazor component](https://github.com/erossini/BlazorChartjs) as a facade of ChartJs. I opened a question on the [Microsoft forum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/852437/how-can-i-link-a-custom-function-to-a-chartjs-via.html?childToView=853751#answer-853751) to understand how I can call a JavaScript function for the component.

My problem is how to add some events to the chart before the creation. So, from the Blazor page, I pass a model called `config` that contains all the configuration for the chart.

Then, I create the chart in JavaScript like

```
var ctx = document.getElementById(id).getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, eval(config));
```

Now, I want to add an event and send to Blazor an event. For example, I added the following code for the event `onHover` and it works.

```
chart.options.onHover = function () {
    DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('PSC.Blazor.Components.Chartjs', 'ChartHover');
}
```

With `onClick` is working too.

```
chart.options.onClick = function (event, array) {
    var rtn = 0;

    if (array !== undefined && array.length > 0)
        rtn = array[0].index;

    DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('PSC.Blazor.Components.Chartjs', 'ChartClick', rtn);
};
```

Now, I want to do the same with `onAnimationComplete`.

```
chart.onAnimationComplete = window["AnimationComplete1"];
```

In this cases, the function is not being called. Some if I write this code

```
chart.onAnimationComplete = function () {
    console.log('onAnimationComplete animation completed');
};
```

How can I fix the code?

Answer (score 0):

there is no `onAnimationComplete` event you can configure directly on the chart. This has to be done in the options like you did for the `onHover` and the name has to be different:

```
chart.options.animation.onComplete = function () {}
```